# Recreating QGIS SAGA polygon self-intersection in python?

Tags: qgis, python, geopandas, shapely, pandas

so I am trying to find a way to re-create the SAGA polygon self-intersection tool used in QGIS in python, but I am having some trouble figuring out how to organize the workflow. with the SAGA polygon self-intersection tool, let's say you have these 3 overlapping buffer polygons provided by a single shapefile, and so each polygon here A, B, and C, corresponds to a separate row in the attribute table:
[image]

Running polygon self-intersection on this layer through the SAGA polygon self-intersection tool in QGIS will then produce a new layer that has the "intersection" geometries make up the rows of the attribute table, and so each intersection zone becomes a unique polygon, but, with the original polygons that make up each intersection polygon identified, like so:

[image]

And so for this output layer, the attribute table would now have 7 rows, one for each new polygon created by the self-intersection, rather than just the 3 initial buffer polygons, A, B, and C. And there will be an "ID" column that will contain a string for each row identifying the polygons that made up that particular intersection polygon as a list like shown in the image above. And so if the intersection polygon was an overlap between polygons A and C, the string value would be "A | C", and if the intersection polygon was an overlap between polygons A, B, and C, the string value would be "A | B | C", etc. That ID column there is what I am after and am having difficulty producing in python.

In python, I am familiar with Pandas, Geopandas and Shapely.

Comment: Union > Delete duplicate geometries > Join attributes by location

Comment: What library, what hat have you tried because unless you add a Python code attempt your question will be closed

Comment: hah, already is. Thank you, didn't know that. Well, I don't have the code. I need ideas on what to use in solving this process in Pandas, Shapely or Geopandas.